# SQL Select with difficult grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

Existing table t:

```
namz varchar2(255), sumz number, datez date
-------------------------------------------
John                100.50       01.01.2016
Ivan                200.45       02.02.2014
...
John                400.32       03.03.2016
```

Can I get grouped monthly sales for defining period by using simple one select:

```
select namz, .... from t where datez>date1 and datez<=date2 and  ....
```

and get result like:

```
namz 01.2014  02.2014  03.2014 .... 03.2016
-------------------------------------------
John null     1200.34  234.34 ...   null
Ivan 1234.45  null     null   ...   254.23
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is called pivot

Comment: Is it a pre-defined set of months? Then you can do a GROUP BY, have case expressions in the select list where you pick data for each month.

Comment: If you have a reporting layer or app layer that you are using to present the data, pivoting is _much_ easier there than trying to do it in SQL.  You can use `PIVOT` and other mechanisms, but the columns must be specified in the SQL.  Most reporting tools and application layers (e.g. java, C#) can more easily do dynamic pivoting based on the data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the dataset

```
CREATE TABLE tmp AS 
(SELECT 'John' name, 100.5 Sumz, '01-Jan-16' datez FROM dual UNION
SELECT 'Ivan' name, 200.45 Sumz, '02-Feb-14' datez FROM dual UNION 
SELECT 'John' name, 400.32 Sumz, '03-Mar-16' datez FROM dual UNION
SELECT 'John' name, 200.0 Sumz, '03-Mar-16' datez FROM dual UNION
SELECT 'John' name, 8475.36 Sumz, '01-Jan-18' datez FROM dual UNION
SELECT 'Ivan' name, 8759.36 Sumz, '03-Mar-16' datez FROM dual)
;
```

Use the pivot statement

```
select * FROM 
(
  SELECT name, sumz, datez
  FROM tmp
)
PIVOT
(
  Sum(sumz)
  FOR datez IN ('01-Jan-16','02-Feb-14','03-Mar-16', '01-Jan-18')
)
ORDER BY name;
```

It gives you exactly what you want

Comment: OP wanted it grouped by months not by days.

Comment: Also, `datez` is probably a `DATE` column and you are implicitly converting the `DATE` values to their string equivalent - this is dependent on an implicit call to `TO_CHAR()` using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as the format mask. While the format mask matches the `PIVOT` values this will work but as soon as the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter is changed the query will break (but you won't have modified the query so it will be a pain to debug). You ought to use `DATE` literals as the pivot values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `CONCAT` like this :

```
SELECT namz, CONCAT(MONTH(datez),'.',YEAR(datez)) as d, SUM(something) as s
FROM t
WHERE datez>date1
AND   datez<=date2
GROUP BY namz, d
```

The result will be like :

```
namez d       s
---------------------
Ivan  01.2014 1234.45
John  02.2014 1200.34
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT namz,
       SUM( CASE WHEN datez >= DATE '2014-01-01'
                  AND datez  < DATE '2014-02-01'
                 THEN sumz END ) AS "01.2014",
       SUM( CASE WHEN datez >= DATE '2014-02-01'
                  AND datez  < DATE '2014-03-01'
                 THEN sumz END ) AS "02.2014",
       SUM( CASE WHEN datez >= DATE '2014-03-01'
                  AND datez  < DATE '2014-04-01'
                 THEN sumz END ) AS "03.2014"
       -- ...
FROM   t
WHERE  datez >  :date1
AND    datez <= :date2
GROUP BY namz
```

Comment: I can't know in advance quantity of month for constructing select expressions with necessary `sum ( case ...).

Comment: @Joysi - You need to know the same information to be able to use `PIVOT`.